# How to compare array Field with Array input value in $filter mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I willing to apply $filter in this collection to get only "Applied Mathematics" result only in array. I am providing input in form of array like this ["Applied Mathematics"] to below collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a95d81eead32e82932b535"),
    "univisorEducation" : [
        {
            "educationLevel" : "BACHELOR",
            "courseType" : "UNDERGRADUATE",
            "year" : 2016,
            "college" : ObjectId("58a936add48f2b502858a70d"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a95eb2eead32e82932b541"),
            "course" : [
                "Anthropology",
                "Biomedical Engineering",
                "Applied Mathematics"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a9643deead32e82932b54b"),
    "univisorEducation" : [
        {
            "educationLevel" : "DOCTORATE",
            "courseType" : "GRADUATE",
            "year" : 2020,
            "college" : ObjectId("58a936afd48f2b502858b5e2"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a96495eead32e82932b550"),
            "course" : [
                "Applied Mathematics",
                "Applied Physics"
            ]
        },
        {
            "educationLevel" : "MASTER",
            "courseType" : "GRADUATE",
            "year" : 2020,
            "college" : ObjectId("58a936afd48f2b502858b9f7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a96495eead32e82932b54f"),
            "course" : [
                "Applied Mathematics"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For this purpose i am using a $filter in $project, below is my $filter code

```
 $filter: {
            input: "$univisorEducation",
            as: "univisorEducation",
            cond: {
                $setIsSubset: ["$$univisorEducation.course", courses]
            }
        }
```

Issue is that i am only getting this result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a95d81eead32e82932b535"), "univisorEducation" : [ ] }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a9643deead32e82932b54b"),
    "univisorEducation" : [
        {
            "educationLevel" : "MASTER",
            "courseType" : "GRADUATE",
            "year" : 2020,
            "college" : ObjectId("58a936afd48f2b502858b9f7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58a96495eead32e82932b54f"),
            "course" : [
                "Applied Mathematics"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The collection with "_id" : ObjectId("58a95d81eead32e82932b535") should have result with Applied Mathematics.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Subset operation is not symmetric. What is your expected output ?

Comment: What i want is to Filter array field data based on array input value

Comment: What is your question ? You are getting expected result using first query. Why are expecting second query to return same results when it is completely different query ?

Comment: I have updated my question. is this time understandable for you ? This is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$filter` aggregation to below.

Compares `courses` array to `univisorEducation.course` and returns true there is match `univisorEducation.course` or false otherwise.

```
$filter: {
    input: "$univisorEducation",
    as: "univisorEducation",
    cond: {
        $ne:[{$setIntersection: [courses, "$$univisorEducation.course" ]}, []]
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that previously . i got the desired result but if input course array like this  ["Applied Mathematics", "Chemistry and Physics"] . i got no result. is there any way to accomplish the desired result

Comment: Makes sense. Updated answer. Please verify.